# Methods to calculate confidence interval for proportion with potential bounds?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, simulation, proportion

I am trying to calculate the confidence interval on a time series proportion.  For example, I have 1000 years of data, and I use 20 days to calculate some proportion.  The thing is, I know the proportion should be closer to 0 than closer to 1.  In fact, I hypothesize that it should be between 0 and 0.20 almost 100% of the time, and I'd imagine 90% would be a lot tighter.

I've briefly glanced at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/five-confidence-intervals-for-proportions-that-you-should-know-about-7ff5484c024f.  Wald gives me something too wide, and the other methods, I haven't looked through.

Is there a way to simulate? Could I assume if I have 1000 days of data, make that the population proportion?

Comment: You don't seem to be using any time series properties.  How, then, does your question differ from estimating a proportion from any sample?  What does your title mean by "potential bounds"? In the text you refer to some suppositions, but they play no apparent role in the analysis or conclusions--unless perhaps you are trying to ask a question about Bayesian credible intervals.  Even then, those suppositions are not "bounds," strictly speaking.

Comment: Well there's only certain values that the proportion can take on.   I don't see the proportion taking on say a value above 0.2 yet the confidence interval sometimes is above it.  I'm just trying to think of other methods to produce intervals that is based in some statistical theory.  I'm getting intervals that are a bit too wide to make sense in reality - so trying to think of ways to narrow it.

Comment: You narrow an interval by collecting more data or else by demonstrating your current method is inapplicable and applying a relevant one.  But you haven't provided any evidence of inapplicability.  When an interval extends beyond where you think it ought to, that's not necessarily an error or evidence of an inferior procedure.  As it stands, your question, in outline, seems to be "I am unhappy with the results of a statistical procedure: how do I make it conform to my expectations?" That's hard to answer without more details.